# Accesing array inside of object with ng-src

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

lately, I've been trying to show some images but I can't figure out why this is happening:
I have an array of objetcs coming from the back-end as follows:

```
  [
  {
    Description:"blablablalb",
    title:"blablabla",
    images:[
    {
      path:1.jpg
    },
    {
      path:2.jpg
    }
   ]
  }
  ]
```

Now, I want to show the images with the information, so I have the next structure:

```
<section class="workThumbnailContainer" ng-repeat="work in works">
            <figure>
                <a href="#"><img class="workThumbnail" ng-src="{{assets/img/work.images[0].path}}"></a>
                <figcaption class="workThumbnailTitle"><a ui-sref="work_details({id:work.idwork})" >{{work.title}}</a></figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section>
```

Everything is working well excep this piece of code:

```
 ng-src="{{assets/img/work.images[0].path}}
```

That gives me a NaN in the attribute, could somebody kindly explain me why this is happening? 
Note: if I use {{work.images[0].path}} outside the ng-src, I get the image path as expected 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ng-src="assets/img/{{work.images[0].path}}"
```

Your current version isn't working because everything inside of {{}} has to be a valid angular expression.  "assets/img/" is a syntax error when evaluated as an expression.

Comment: That's just about right, I just figured it out! thanks for taking your time, I used : {{'assets/img/'+work.images[0].path}}